# How are transactions partitioned/isolated in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have been reading the SQLite documentation and also referencing code I have written previously but I don't seem to be able to find a definitive answer to what I imagine to be a rather simple question.

I would like to execute many (separate) compiled statements within a transaction, but child threads may also be creating transactions or just executing statements at the same time and I would not want them included in this particular transaction.  Currently, I have a single database handle that I share between all threads.

So, my question is,

1) .. is it generally better to have some kind of semaphore around transactions to ensure they will not clash/collect with other statements being executed against a database handle. I already marshal writes to prevent problems with multithreaded issues with SQLite (although with WAL now it's very hard to unsettle it at all).

2) .. or are you expected to open multiple database connections and start/commit the transactions one per database connection if they will be concurrent?

Comment: Ah sorry,  I was unable too as it had been marked as a duplicate.   Will do that now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changes made in one database connection are invisible to all other database connections prior to commit.

So it seems a hybrid approach of having several connections open to the database provides adequate concurrency guarantees, trading off the expense of opening a new connection with the benefit of allowing multi-threaded write transactions.

A query sees all changes that are completed on the same database connection prior to the start of the query, regardless of whether or not those changes have been committed.

If changes occur on the same database connection after a query starts running but before the query completes, then it is undefined whether or not the query will see those changes.

If changes occur on the same database connection after a query starts running but before the query completes, then the query might return a changed row more than once, or it might return a row that was previously deleted.

For the purposes of the previous four items, two database connections that use the same shared cache and which enable PRAGMA `read_uncommitted` are considered to be the same database connection, not separate database connections.

---

Here is the SQLite [information on isolation](https://www.sqlite.org/isolation.html).  Which is exceptionally useful to read and understand for this problem.